# Strange UpdateSourceTrigger behaviour for combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a combo box for which I change the values of the selected items in the bound property setter. The value is not reflected in the combobox in View. When I select 2 in UI, it should show 3 but it shows 2. 
I don't understand why it doesn't work even though I set the updatesourcetrigger to Propertychanged.

```
 public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _selected;
    public List<int> MyList => new List<int>() {1, 2, 3};

    public int Selected
    {
        get => _selected;
        set
        {
            _selected = value;
            if (value == 2)
                _selected = 3;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and my view is

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox Height="50" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  ></ComboBox>

</StackPanel>
```

However, I noticed that if I add a Delay or change UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus, it works fine.
Can anyone explain why it doesn't work in the first case even if propertychanged is fired from source to target?

Code with a delay which works

```
 <ComboBox Height="50" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected,Mode=TwoWay,Delay=1}"  ></ComboBox>
```

Also out of curiosity I added a textbox to my view ,binded the same with selecteditem with same updatesourcetrigger. But to my surprise when I enter 2 in textbox,it changes to 3 and updates combobox too.I find it difficult to understand why this doesnt work witn combobox?

```
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ComboBox Height="50" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  ></ComboBox>
        <TextBox Height="50" Width="200" Text="{Binding Selected,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: This isn't actually a problem, but a feature. Imagine a ComboBox that would *not* ignore SelectedItem property changes while the user is interacting with it.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, but what I dont understand is when propertychanged event is raised with new value, its not updated in view but with a delay its updated .What changes between these two situations?

Comment: Can you show an example of code with this "delay"?

Comment: Obviously, with a delay the PropertyChanged event is fired *after* user interaction has ended.

Comment: @Clemens do you have any link that documents this feature you're talking about?

Comment: @Clemens So you mean to say in my first situation , propertychanged event was fired from setter when I just selected the value in combobox and after the user interaction ended ,it got lost. Where did the event go,who handled it? I am just asking sequence of events in my first situation.

Comment: I can't say how exactly it's implemented. It just seems to make much sense for a ComboBox not to handle a changed property value while it is itself updating the property.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks , but I am interested in "How it works"  so asked this question. Ofcourse there are solutions all over SO(Thats why moderator marked my question duplicate) but I want to understand what causes the problem at the first place, which I didn't find anywhere.

Comment: Well, inspect the reference source.